# Simulate d-pad center key to touchpad for android phones

Tags: android, touchpad

how do you simulate a "d-pad center key" with a touchpad? I'm using Samsung Galaxy Y / GTS5360

Comment: Can you be more specific?  As in, you want to emulate a d-pad center key touch from code?  Or add a button to a custom keyboard that pretends to be a dpad?  Or just, as a user, perform some action that the system will then pretend was a d-pad center key touch?

Comment: As a user, a third party app requires that I need to push the center d-pad. I only have a touchpad in my hardware.

Comment: This app is designed pretty poorly if there is no other way to achieve the effect.. The absolute majority of devices do not have a hardware keyboard.

Comment: Alexander, do you know how to " emulate a d-pad center key touch from code" ?. I would love to hear about this. Thanks